# Issue while redirecting the console output to text file using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Am trying to redirect the console output to text file using batch file.The following is the command I used to redirect.

```
for /f  %%a in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get Version') do echo %%a >> out.txt

set /p var =< out.txt

echo var=%var%
```

### **Output:**

var=0

If I execute the below command,am getting the version value properly.

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get Version') do echo %%a
```

### **Output:**

Version

8.0.56336

Even I tried to assign Command output to Variable, am getting null value. The command is

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable'" get Version') do set ver=%%a

echo ver:%ver%
```

### **Output:**

ver:

Can anyone please suggest me where I did the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect a console output to a text file use the > operator

run the .exe file generated in VS2005 in the debug folder in your CMD as

yourfilename.exe >output.txt

Comment: Initially I tried with single > only.But i didn't get any.For test purpose I used >>.

Comment: use CMD in admin mode maybe the writing privileges are only for an admin for that current folder. Coz i have tried it it works. one more thing which os are you using? Win7,8,8.1 or XP ? coz it works in 7,8,8.1 no idea about XP